# What java regex can I use to match this string?

Tags: java, regex, string-matching, data-manipulation

****EDIT2*** Regex was not the necessarily the best way to solve this one. All I had to do was validate that data[i] did not contain a '#' character.*

***EDIT** I forgot to mention that this is for validation. I do split the string by semi colon however these are part of a much larger file I need to parse through and obviously I don't want my parser to break when it tries to split a string not containing ";"*

---

I want a regex expression to match the following example strings. I have done all of this already with individual expressions (minus the semi-colons), but am a regex newb so have had trouble with this one.

```
2013/11/06 15:34:01;website.some.net;80;43.121.103.95
2013/11/06 15:45:15;site.test.com;8080;43.22.118.51
```

Broken down it is

`date` *space* `HH:MM:SS` *semi-colon* `URI` *semi-colon* `PortNumber` *semi-colon* `IPv4Address`

Here is the regex I have used for individual components in the past.

Date and time - `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})`

URI - `(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?") && !data[i].matches("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$`

Port number - `^\+?\d+$`

IPv4 address - `^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$`

My Parser method:

```
public void setList(String Page){

        String[] data = Page.toLowerCase().replace("#comment#", "").split(";"); //remove comments
        String[] dateTime = null; //date time array
        String formattedIP = null; //stores the parsed IP address
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                if(data[i].contains("/")){ //date and time field
                    dateTime = data[i].split(" ");
                    dates.add(dateTime[0].substring(dateTime[0].indexOf('/') - 4 ));
                    times.add(dateTime[1]);
                }

                formattedIP = data[i].replace(dateTime[0].substring(dateTime[0].indexOf('/') - 4 ),"").replace(dateTime[1], "").trim();
                if(formattedIP.matches("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$")){
                    IPs.add(formattedIP);

                }

                if(data[i].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                    ports.add(data[i]);

                }

                if(data[i].matches("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?") && !data[i].matches("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$")){
                    URIs.add(data[i]);
                }
        }


    }
```

Comment: If all your patterns work, why don't you declare them as `String`s first, the compile the `Pattern` by concatenating all `String`s? Note that you'd have to remove input start/end characters (`^` and `$`)...

Comment: You may want to split your string on ";" and then regular expression each portion individually. that seems easier

Comment: you could just do `([^;]+);` and repeat for the number of `;` you have...are you wanting to use this to also validate the data? or just break it apart?

Comment: Your parser won't break when you split a string not containing ";". If a string is supposed to have 5 semi colons, then after splitting check length==6. If not, then the input is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to match the whole line. Just split the line by `;`:

```
String[] arr = line.split(";");
```

then access/examine/parse individual array components using `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]` etc.

Comment: He'll still have to use some regular expressions after splitting, but the problem will be much more simplified at this point

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually do exactly that, the reason I need this particular regex is for validating it is in said format.

Comment: @JaminBecker so validate each element of the array separately

Comment: @JaminBecker: It is much easier to validate an individual array element.

Comment: @JaminBecker but if you absolutely want to do it with a single regex, then why not just put a ";" between all the regexes you have, and put it together as one string?

Comment: See though, the problem doing that way is if one of those elements isn't valid, I have to assume the next other three aren't either... For example #SomeComment#2013/11/06 15:45:15;site.test.com;8080;43.22.118.51 causes the array to store bad data and somewhere down the road I get a null pointer exception... I want to remove any bad strings before splitting into an array

Comment: @JaminBecker If one of them is invalid, then they all are. What's the problem with that? `boolean valid = validateDate(arr[0]) && validateTime(arr[1]) && ...`

Comment: @Cruncher, because I know that my regex is terrible haha, and I know that it can be done so much more eloquently than that.

Comment: @JaminBecker if you expect this regex to be less than sum(your regexes) then you're crazy. Unless your current regexes as are can be shortened, but there's no way of using the fact that you're combining them, to make them any shorter. Each section has different criteria for validation.

Comment: @Cruncher you're absolutely right, validating a position in the array was the easiest way to solve this problem! I feel dumb for not thinking of it...

Comment: @JaminBecker: Looks like this split approach worked for you. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: I had actually used the split approach prior to this. My problem was forgetting how easily I could validate data once it was in an array as long as I prevented any of the following values from being added to my Lists.

Answer (score 1):

> per @Cruncher 
>         @JaminBecker If one of them is invalid, then they all are. What's the problem with that? boolean valid = validateDate(arr[0]) &&
>   validateTime(arr[1]) && ...

Thus I simply make sure that the current index of the array I split from the string doesn't contain comments, much better solution
 then complex regex below is my amended parser method

```
public void setList(String Page){
    String[] data = Page.toLowerCase().split(";"); //remove comments
    String[] dateTime = null; //date time array
    String formattedIP = null; //stores the parsed IP address
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        **if(!data[i].contains("#")){**
            if(data[i].contains("/")){ //date and time field
                System.out.println(data[i]);
                dateTime = data[i].split(" ");
                dates.add(dateTime[0].substring(dateTime[0].indexOf('/') - 4 ));
                times.add(dateTime[1]);
            }

            formattedIP = data[i].replace(dateTime[0].substring(dateTime[0].indexOf('/') - 4 ),"").replace(dateTime[1], "").trim();
            if(formattedIP.matches("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$")){
                IPs.add(formattedIP);

            }

            if(data[i].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                ports.add(data[i]);

            }

            if(data[i].matches("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?") && !data[i].matches("^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +"([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$")){
                URIs.add(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }


}
```